# What component is this that Visual Studio uses?

Tags: visual-studio, uicomponents

Does anyone know what component this is? (The expanded option toolbox, where I can click on it and it opens a lot of options, I can put in the left side of the form or the right.)

I don't think it's a treeview (or is it a customized treeview?).

If there isn't such component, how can I implement it?

[image: Toolbox]

Comment: It is custom, but a TreeView will work just fine.

Comment: A TreeView can display an icon, use the TreeNode.ImageIndex property.  You'd need DrawItem to get the highlight.  Check the MSDN Library, it's all there.

Comment: @Hans: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted. Its using the WPF application, the component Expander, found on Controls tab.